# Kerberos and LDAP complex relationship

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap, kerberos, authorization

I have problems understanding the relationship between LDAP and Kerberos (Conceptually).

I understand LDAP as a directory service, and Kerberos as an authentication service.

We also know that LDAP is also capable of storing passwords, but LDAP's design is to be a publicly accessible directory, and not suitable for storing sensitive information. That's why it's preferred to delegate authentication to another service, like Kerberos.

Now what I don't understand are these two questions:

1. To which server do clients send their request when a user tries to log in? My intuition tells me it must be the Kerberos server. If yes, where does the LDAP server comes in?
2. Where do the sysadmin sets permissions? In this case my intuition tells me LDAP. I can imagine that there could be an entry for each system and/or service, and users will be given access to them through group memberships or directly. If yes, does it mean the LDAP server (through an interface like phpLDAPadmin) will set groups and users accordingly in Kerberos server?

I'm particularly confused cause I see the connection between LDAP and Kerberos in both documentations. LDAP talks about delegating authentication to Kerberos [here](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#SASL%20Authentication), and Kerberos talks about having LDAP as a backend [here](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.13/doc/admin/conf_ldap.html).

All the documentations I read seem to be pieces of a puzzle that I can't manage to put together. I appreciate if someone could explain how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, it's been a long time.  Let's see what I can remember.

Yes, it can definitely be confusing because you can use Kerberos to authenticate for LDAP, and you can also have Kerberos use LDAP as a backend.  Although they are not the same thing, it's often hard to differentiate which one is being talked about when you try to search for it.  I can only talk about LDAP using Kerberos for its authentication since I have no experience with it the other way around.

1. Your intuition is right that it uses the Kerberos server.  As I understand it, the client requests a TGT from the Kerberos server FOR the LDAP server (using the service principal name of "ldap/hostname@DOMAIN.NAME" or similar).  The client can then use this to log in to the LDAP server since it is able to validate the ticket.  The client password itself is never sent to the LDAP server.
2. This is if you are using LDAP as a backend for Kerberos I imagine.  You could use an LDAP directory here to save attributes and values for various things.  You, of course, do not *have* to use LDAP as a back-end for Kerberos.

Things get even more convoluted when they start talking about SASL because it's difficult to tell whether they are talking about SASL on the front end or the back end of LDAP.  In other words, is it being used by the clients to authenticate to LDAP?  Or is it being used by LDAP to pass along the password to another authentication source?  Just caveats to watch for.

As an aside: It is possible to use a simple bind with LDAP, send the password to the LDAP server, which then passes the password along to another authentication source (like Kerberos).  If you are doing something like that, it's nice because the password itself isn't stored in LDAP, but since a simple bind is clear text, you'd want to make sure to use TLS between the client and LDAP server.

Hope this helps just a little.  Sounds like you've basically got the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is on track in both cases. Let's take both your questions one by one.

1. Here, the kerberos service is the **authentication** system. The client will receive an encrypted ticket from the kerberos server (upon successful authentication of course), and will then present this to the server to show they are authenticated.
2. Here, the ldap service is the **authorisation** system. User information is stored in the directory (such as UID / GID etc). In essence this replaces the information in /etc/passwd. The ldap server does not update any information in the kerberos server.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your setup.  I've been wrestling with this for a little while, but I'm no expert.

For a system administrator, the relationship between LDAP and Kerberos could be as simple as a machine using both of them.  Your setup could be as simple as using LDAP as a source for /etc/passwd and /etc/group via nsswitch.conf (and a plugin like nss-pam-ldapd from archlinux repo), leaving the userPassword attribute in LDAP as an exclamation point or asterisk (meaning no password and no ability to login).

A Kerberos KDC providing the password authentication for whatever machines you want, where the system login integration would differ depending on the service it offered.  For instance, if it is a remote machine only requiring access via ssh, LDAP still provides the same info as everywhere else, but Kerberos only needs a few lines in the ssh configuration files.  On another system where full login integration is required, this could end up being a HUGE pain in the arse, because it requires making many changes to PAMs configuration.  This is easy in RHEL clients with authconfig, but expect it to be a huge headache elsewhere unless you are comfortable with PAM.  The positive thing about getting it to work with PAM though, is that most programs (like ssh) can use PAM, so you don't need to worry about the ssh config anymore.

In other words, if KDC is down, the system won't ever accept your password right or not (but it knows you are a user because of LDAP), and if the LDAP server is down, the system will think your username doesn't exist.

Comment: @adrin the 'permissions' can come in the system integration portion.  If you are using nss (linux/unix) to integrate kerberos authentication into the system's authorization, you can do some authorization mapping in /etc/nsswitch.conf [http://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/], or you can refer to [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication] for some other mapping options...